# Как скопировать с заменой текст из одного 1.txt в другой 2.txt с помощью батника?

Tags: bat

Есть 1.txt в котором есть всего лишь одна строка, **которая всегда меняется**, обозначим текст строки ***.

Есть 2.txt в котором есть текст и в котором нужно заменить определенные слова.

К примеру 2.txt имеет такой текст:

```
;MAIN_ALIAS=10.1.9.36:d:\data\pm.gdb
MAIN_ALIAS=C:\GIVC\Mshp\DATA\DB.GDB
;MAIN_ALIAS=10.1.9.36:D:\DHP\OP\NEW_OP.GDB
```

в нем нужно заменить `C:\GIVC\Mshp`
на текст с файла 1.txt `***`, и чтобы получилось в итоге вот такое

```
;MAIN_ALIAS=10.1.9.36:d:\data\pm.gdb
MAIN_ALIAS=***\DATA\DB.GDB
;MAIN_ALIAS=10.1.9.36:D:\DHP\OP\NEW_OP.GDB
```

Ранее с батниками не приходилось работать, это разовая задача,которую мне сказали сделать. Читаю и пытаюсь, но не совсем правильно получается.С Батниками познакомился давно, в универе когда ещё был и то, поверхностно. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: "_это разовая задача_" правильно ли я понимаю, что вы не хотите разбираться с тем, как работают `.bat` файлы а просто хотите получить готовое решение?

Comment: Как понять "всегда меняется"?

Comment: Как понять, какие "оперделённые слова" нужно заменить?

Comment: Вам без разницы на чём этом будет реализовано?

Comment: "Как понять "всегда меняется"?" - там текст не постоянный, он от место расположения другого файла, поэтому я и обозначил его как ***

Comment: @hedgehogues "Как понять, какие "оперделённые слова" нужно заменить? " то что заменять, не меняется "C:\GIVC\Mshp" он всегда будет во 2.txt

Comment: "Вам без разницы на чём этом будет реализовано?" ну да, главное чтобы задача решилась...ну и я примерно понимал что как делается

Comment: @DmitriySimushev в некотором роде я понимаю как они работают, но для дальнейшего мне они не приходятся.

Comment: @РомаХайновский файл 2 не изменяется? Он для всякого файла 1 одинаковый?

Comment: @hedgehogues да, 2 не изменяется, он всегда одинаковый, меняется только 1

Comment: Смотри команду for. Вероятно, ей можно скормить разделитель эту строку, а там уже через echo выводить то, что требуется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментариях к вопросу сказано, что начальный текст второго файла всегда одинаковый. Учитывая это, предлагаю не пытаться парсить его, а формировать заново.

```
@echo off

set /p text=< 1.txt

echo ;MAIN_ALIAS=10.1.9.36:d:\data\pm.gdb       > 2.txt
echo MAIN_ALIAS=%text%\DATA\DB.GDB              >> 2.txt
echo ;MAIN_ALIAS=10.1.9.36:D:\DHP\OP\NEW_OP.GDB >> 2.txt
```

То есть не важно, что есть во втором файле (и вообще есть ли он). Читаются данные из первого файла в переменную `text`, затем во второй файл записываются нужные строки со значением этой переменной.

Comment: спасибо большое, все работает.